# Does Midnight Commander cancel a background copy if another background copy is initiated?

Tags: shell, terminal, file-copy, mc

I just wanted to confirm this behaviour. If I copy something in Midnight Commander with the option to put it in the background and then I start a second process of copying something in that same Midnight Commander console, does this break the first process? I have the feeling it does.

And does somebody know how to get a visual output about the state of the background process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found out what happened. Midnight Commander can handle several background processes. But it might stop them if Midnight Commander is exited. It will, however, resume on restart.